# How to explicitly close a JQuery dialogue without triggering close event?

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

I want to close a JQuery Dialogue without triggering its close event.
I am using $(this).dialog("close") in the dialogue function.
Could you please help me ?

Answer (score 1):

You need to replace this with appropriate selector. Something like this:

```
 $('#dialog').dialog('close');
```

Answer (score 0):

This is the another way

$('#dialog').dialog('option', 'close', null);